How to build from webpack 4 to without breaking Content-Security-Policy of not using 'unsafe-eval'?
I'm trying to build  through webpack 4 & npm . i facing issue of "EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive:" . I can not allow 'unsafe-eval' in response header due to security reason which client have asked.
I have also tried webpack devtool option nither option is working.

there are many ways for eval to be emitted, it can be from your own js code, libraries, or webpack through script loader or source maps as this github issue suggested. have you tried any of those? it kinda difficult to replicate the issue without knowing your code - or at least webpack config and libraries used.

@BagusTesa     yes i have tried above link already . it was from package react-slick so i have updated that package because someone fixed on that packages using null instead of new Function() which was main point of error in code.
